# HTML5 background video with bootstrap overlay content

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

I'm currently trying to create a div in bootstrap that has two columns inside, and a background video for the entire div. Problem is, I can't do it and preserve the column content, and do it all responsively.

I've attached a fiddle - the red is where I need the video to appear (with a poster frame for compatibility purposes).

Any ideas of best way to do this? Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/by07or2p/#&togetherjs=DmdvnAF3Td

The video portion is below as I had to write code to be able to post:

```
<video autoplay>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Check the updated fiddle in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use position relative to the parent div then position absolute top/left/bottom/right depending on your needs on the child div. This is also very good article about videos which you can use [Fluid Width Video](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Comment: Thanks - won't that affect it being responsive though?

Answer (score 0):

Updated Fiddle:

<kbd>[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b3k1wLeg/)</kbd>

---

Add id to your video tag `id='video-background'`

```
<video autoplay id='video-background'>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Change css

```
#video-background {
  position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


.hero {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Updated Fiddle:

<kbd>[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3k1wLeg/)</kbd>

Comment: Was it not what you asked in OP ?

Comment: Thanks - this creates a full page video though - I need it to be the background video to the div only.